# perl and regex to extract a path

Tags: regex, perl

I have a block of text/code where I need to search for include= and then grab the entire path after the '=' I've tried several ways and I just can't seem to get what I'm looking for in the chunk of code/text:

```
include=Y:\default\main\tsconfig\custom\inline\callouts\search\results.
```

assume this is the xml being searched:

```
<item name="Post Include Code">
<value>
First section of content

include=Y:\default\main\tsconfig\tsconfig\custom\inline\callouts\search\results.tpl
Second section of content
</value>

</item>
```

The code:

```
if ($includeText=~ s/include=(.*)$/\1/) { 
    print "$1";
}
else { 
    print "no path";
}
```

I want to end up with `Y:\default\main\tsconfig\custom\inline\callouts\search\results.tpl` so that I can include a template. The text/code is pulled from another file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I made a small change in your script and its working:

```
$include = "include=Y:\\default\\main\\tsconfig\\custom\\inline\\callouts\\search\\results.";


if ($include =~ m/include=(.*)$/) { 
    print "$1";
}
else { 
    print "no path";
}
```

Comment: Except that grabs the include too. He wants just after the equal sign, so `[^include=]` would be needed to exclude that part.

Comment: @Mike - "include" is not in the capture group and so will not be returned in `$1`

Comment: I suspect he can't change the input text, but rather is looking for a regex to extract it.

Comment: My assumption is the variable $include will have a line as mentioned in my example

Comment: I can change the input text but it isn't my preference

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate, I took your script, used it, and it works just fine. There is nothing wrong with your regex, but rather with your other code, which you have not shown.

Also: A bit more info about what your problem is would be great. "I just can't seem to get.." doesn't really tell us much about what's going wrong.

My *guess* is that you are not using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

And that you therefore have done something silly such as:

```
while ($includetext = <DATA>) {
    if ($includeText =~ s/...)
```

---

This script works:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (s/include=(.*)$/$1/) { 
            print "$1";
    }
    else { 
            print "no path";
    }
}

__DATA__
include=Y:\default\main\tsconfig\custom\inline\callouts\search\results.
```

Comment: That really is the code in a nutshell. I simplifed the data portion which grabs a chunk of text from an xml file. I am just as confused as you are why it won't work.

Comment: Let me add that after checking just the include+... in the data it works. I'm assuming it doesn't work because it is not the only text being examined and there can be whitespace and line breaks in the content that is being searched. I'm wondering what would make this work in the "s/include=(.*)$/$1/" manner that you suggested. it seemed like the obvious choice and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;
my $inc='include=Y:\default\main\tsconfig\custom\inline\callouts\search\results.tpl';
if ($inc =~ m{include=([\w\:\\\w /]+\w+\.\w+)} )
{
print $1;
}
else
{
print "no path";
}
```

Comment: This works to a degree. the string being evaluated is a content area that I am searching for the include= and there is potential for there to be whitespace and line breaks in this content area. so content that appears after the path is being printed to the screen as well.

Assume we are using the following from an xml file:

<item name="Post Include Code">
<value>
First section of content


include=Y:\default\main\tsconfig\tsconfig\custom\inline\callouts\search\results.tpl

Second section of content</value>
</item>

Answer (score -3):

You don't want to include the "include=" part. You want just what's after, so you'd have to exclude the "include=" part with something like this: `[^include=].*` (a quick text in a text editor worked for me).

Comment: And what happens when the line says `include=c:\foo`?  Your regex won't capture the `c`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write this as a comment to another answer? It does not seem like a complete answer to me.

Comment: your code is exactly equivalent to [^=cdeilnu].* Do you think that is going to do the Right Thing?

Answer (score -4):

//EDIT:
corrected after looking at a few examples
This seems to work, this is same as Raghuram's post.

```
if($includeText =~ m/include=(.*)$/){
                    print "$1";
                    }
                    else { 
                        print "no path";
                    }
```

Comment: This is incorrect. 1. `==` is used for numerical comparison, not text comparison (use `eq` for that). 2. this will perform the substitution on `$_` and compare the numerical result (i.e. number of matches) with `$includeText`

Comment: @Nathan , yes you are right...
i just missed the point.  operator eq should be used

Comment: no, `eq` will still operate on `$_` but will compare the string result (whatever that is, empty string maybe) with `$includeText`.  As bemace said, the correct operator here is `=~` because the OP wants to apply a regex function to `$includeText`.